# OpenVPN client cant communication with LAN

Tags: networking, openvpn, tomato

I am running FreshTomato 2023.5 and attempting to setup an OpenVPN server.  I can generate the client config and get my iPhone to connect using the openvpn client.  I can then ping the FastTomato router but I cannot ping or otherwise access any machines on the internal LAN.

Following the instructions, I can't see what's configured incorrectly - I understood that ticking "Push LAN0 (br0) to clients" would allow the clients to see machines on the LAN.  Am I missing a rule somewhere?

My FastTomato router is at 192.168.10.1 - the internal LAN is 192.168.10.0/24 and the VPN subnet is 10.6.0.0/24

This router is also the default gateway for my LAN.

BASIC CONFIGURATION:

[image]

ADVANCED CONFIGURATION:

I have also tried checking the "Direct Clients to Redirect Internet Traffic" option with no joy - I am assuming this instructs the client to send all internet traffic down the VPN.  I would prefer just to send traffic destined for the LAN. I believe this is called Split Tunnelling.

[image]

CLIENT LOG (with public ip's and dns names obscured)

```
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] START CONNECTION
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] ----- OpenVPN Start -----
OpenVPN core 3.8.3connect1 ios arm64 64-bit
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] OpenVPN core 3.8.3connect1 ios arm64 64-bit
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] Frame=512/2112/512 mssfix-ctrl=1250
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] NOTE: This configuration contains options that were not used:
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] Unsupported option (ignored)
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] 3 [ncp-ciphers] [CHACHA20-POLY1305:AES-128-GCM:AES-256-GCM:AES-128-CBC:AES-256-CB...]
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] 11 [resolv-retry] [infinite]
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] UNKNOWN/UNSUPPORTED OPTIONS
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] 15 [status] [status]
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] EVENT: RESOLVE
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] Contacting xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1194 via UDP
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] EVENT: WAIT
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] Connecting to [x.x.co.uk]:1194 (86.31.66.136) via UDP
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] EVENT: CONNECTING
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] Tunnel Options:V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1541,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,cipher BF-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 128,key-method 2,tls-client
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] Creds: Username/Password
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] Sending Peer Info:
IV_VER=3.8.3connect1
IV_PLAT=ios
IV_NCP=2
IV_TCPNL=1
IV_PROTO=990
IV_MTU=1600
IV_CIPHERS=AES-128-CBC:AES-192-CBC:AES-256-CBC:AES-128-GCM:AES-192-GCM:AES-256-GCM:CHACHA20-POLY1305
IV_AUTO_SESS=1
IV_GUI_VER=net.openvpn.connect.ios_3.4.1-5463
IV_SSO=webauth,openurl,crtext
IV_BS64DL=1

[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] VERIFY OK: depth=1, /C=GB/ST=Yorks/L=York/O=FreshTomato/OU=IT/CN=server, signature: RSA-SHA256
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] VERIFY OK: depth=0, /C=GB/ST=Yorks/L=York/O=FreshTomato/OU=IT/CN=server, signature: RSA-SHA256
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] SSL Handshake: peer certificate: CN=server, 2048 bit RSA, cipher: TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256   TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any   Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD

[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] Session is ACTIVE
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] EVENT: GET_CONFIG
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] Sending PUSH_REQUEST to server...
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] OPTIONS:
0 [route] [192.168.10.0] [255.255.255.0]
1 [dhcp-option] [DNS] [192.168.10.1]
2 [route-gateway] [10.6.0.1]
3 [topology] [subnet]
4 [ping] [15]
5 [ping-restart] [60]
6 [ifconfig] [10.6.0.2] [255.255.255.0]
7 [peer-id] [0]
8 [cipher] [CHACHA20-POLY1305]

[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] PROTOCOL OPTIONS:
 cipher: CHACHA20-POLY1305
 digest: NONE
 key-derivation: OpenVPN PRF
 compress: NONE
 peer ID: 0
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] EVENT: ASSIGN_IP
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] NIP: preparing TUN network settings
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] NIP: init TUN network settings with endpoint: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] NIP: adding IPv4 address to network settings 10.6.0.2/255.255.255.0
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] NIP: adding (included) IPv4 route 10.6.0.0/24
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] NIP: adding (included) IPv4 route 192.168.10.0/24
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] NIP: adding DNS 192.168.10.1
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] NIP: allowFamily(AF_INET, 1)
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] NIP: allowFamily(AF_INET6, 1)
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] NIP: adding match domain ALL
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] NIP: adding DNS specific routes:
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] NIP: adding (included) IPv4 route 192.168.10.1/32
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] Connected via NetworkExtensionTUN
[Feb 07, 2024, 19:53:13] EVENT: CONNECTED iphone@x.x.co.uk:1194 (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) via /UDP on NetworkExtensionTUN/10.6.0.2/ gw=[/] mtu=(default)
```

CLIENT CONFIG (auto-generated by Tomato 2023.5)

```
remote x.x.x.x 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ncp-ciphers CHACHA20-POLY1305:AES-128-GCM:AES-256-GCM:AES-128-CBC:AES-256-CBC
client
remote-cert-tls server
; ca ca.pem
<ca>
... certs go here
```

Comment: Please show the complete routing table

Comment: Is 192.168.10.1 default gw in your lan?

Comment: Yes 192.168.10.1 is my default gateway.  Where would you like the routing table info from and which command should I run to provide the required output?

Comment: What is the routing table of your client? Does `ping 10.6.0.1` from the client work? Does it work from LAN clients? Does `ping 192.168.10.1` work from VPN client?

Comment: Additionally show us your configuration files, both for server and client.

Comment: I can ping 10.6.0.1 from the VPN client and from the LAN clients.  I have added my client config as generated by Tomato, the server conf is presumably created from the options in the screenshots.

Comment: Do you have any firewall rules to allow traffic? Your VPN is working...

Comment: Not specifically that i'm aware of.  Can you suggest a command I can try?  There is a firewall UP script area that I can past something in to.  I can obviously try from a tty first.

Answer (score -1):

> I can then ping the FastTomato router but I cannot ping or otherwise
> access any machines on the internal LAN.

I am not sure how you installed the Openvpn server, but it looks like you are missing **IP forwarding** (server-side) so this command should fix that:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Some background information: [What is and how do I enable IP forwarding on Linux?](https://openvpn.net/faq/what-is-and-how-do-i-enable-ip-forwarding-on-linux/)

Comment: Traffic on the local subnet is not forwarded by a router.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem.  Running:

`cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` shows the value already to be 1